# Launch Firefox with Python 3.x

Tags: python, firefox, python-3.x, scripting

I'm trying to write a script that will launch firefox for me, open up google in a new tab, and be able to do a search (for instance, www.espn.com). I'm currently trying to achieve this by using the webbrowser module, however I run into an error each time that I try launching Firefox from the script. Also, firefox is not my default browser.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab('http://www.google.com')
```

Whenever I run this I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/test Bing.py", line 6, in <module>
    webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab('http://www.google.com')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\webbrowser.py", line 53, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

I'm unsure why the script is struggling to locate the firefox.exe I have also tried specifying in `'firefox'` the actual location of firefox.exe in c: however I still get the same error.

I'm sure that there's a small error in my code that I currently can't see, if someone could help point out what I'm doing wrong I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4520261/594589

Comment: While that is a nice troubleshooting step, it won't actually register Firefox or any specific browser for use in `webbrowser`.

Comment: what operating system are you using.

Comment: @kylek I'm using Windows XP

Comment: @Julian does my solution work for you, or do you want to use Firefox without modifying the `%path%` variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have Firefox installed on my Windows machine as well, and have the same error.

If you run the following two lines in IDLE:

```
import webbrowser
print webbrowser._browsers # or print(webbrowser._browsers) for Python 3.x
```

Then you'll get a `dict` of available browser controllers, as said in the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/webbrowser.py).  On my system it prints:

```
{'windows-default': [<class 'webbrowser.WindowsDefault'>, None], 
    'c:\\program files\\internet explorer\\iexplore.exe': [None, <webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x01BAF6B0>]
}
```

I have IE, Chrome and Firefox, but only "Default" and "Internet Explorer" appear here.  According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html), the keys `'firefox'` and `'mozilla'` should work, but they are absent here.

From lines 539-563 in the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/webbrowser.py), Python will only register a browser if its corresponding key (e.g. `'firefox'` or `'chrome'`) is a valid command using `_iscommand(cmd)`.

I added the Firefox path to `%path%` and restarted IDLE. `_iscommand('firefox')` returns `True` and `webbrowser.get('firefox)` returns a `<webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x01BDF7F0>`.  However, `webbrowser._iscommand("chrome")` still returns  `False` and  `webbrowser.get("chrome")` still throws the exception.

## Conclusion

You'll have to add the Firefox path to the `%path%` variable first, or make the assumption that Firefox is the default browser.

Comment: I actually just ran the same thing you did to get a list of available browsers and also only got for IE. I haven't coded in python in several years, so I'm a little unsure of where I can add the firefox path.

Comment: The `%path%` variable is for the whole System, not just for Python.  You can find a guide at http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the Firefox executable is on the path (`%PATH%` on Windows, `$PATH` on Linux).