# How can I open a website in my web browser using Python?

Tags: python

I want to open a website in my local computer's web browser (Chrome or Internet Explorer) using Python.

```
open("http://google.co.kr") # something like this
```

Is there a module that can do this for me?

Comment: by 'open' to you mean open for reading?

Comment: or do you mean open up your system browser with that website?

Comment: @sfletche Umm.. it's in Internet Explorer or Chrom

Comment: @lemonhead Yes you are right

Comment: worked for me (watch the backslash) webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe %s").open("https://docs.google.com")

Comment: but why "Path/file.exe %s" works but not this: str(Path/file.exe) or (r"Path/file.exe") ?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module looks promising: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU3P7qz3ZrM

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://google.co.kr', new=2)
```

Comment: Oh thanks you. Can you explain me, what means new=new

Comment: `new` is set to 2 in the example, which opens the url in a new tab.  The default (new=0) will open it in an existing browser window. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open for the spec

Comment: This opens the URL in Chrome on my machine despite Firefox being set as the default browser. Weird.

Comment: Solved: I had to specifically use `webbrowser.get('firefox').open('http://www.google.com', new=2)` despite Firefox already being my default browser.

Comment: It is printing False while running this code on Google-Colab.

Comment: each day i get more amazed at python's base library

Comment: @lemonhead "new tab" and "existing browser window" doesn't contradict

Answer (score 19):

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open).

> The webbrowser module provides a high-level interface to allow
>   displaying Web-based documents to users. Under most circumstances,
>   simply calling the open() function from this module will do the right
>   thing.

You have to import the module and use `open()` function. This will open https://nabinkhadka.com.np in the browser.

**To open in new tab:**

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://nabinkhadka.com.np', new = 2)
```

**Also from the doc.**

> If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser window if possible.
>   If new is 1, a new browser window is opened if possible. If new is 2,
>   a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if possible

So according to the value of new, you can either open page in same browser window or in new tab etc.

Also you can specify as which browser (chrome, firebox, etc.) to open. Use **get()** function for this.

Comment: Can this be downloaded using `sudo pip install webbrowser`?

Comment: @zygimantus This already comes with python. No need to install it. :)

Answer (score 13):

As the instructions state, using the open() function does work, and opens the default web browser - usually I would say: "why wouldn't I want to use Firefox?!" (my default and favorite browser)

```
import webbrowser as wb
wb.open_new_tab('http://www.google.com')
```

The above should work for the computer's default browser. However, what if you want to  to open in Google Chrome?

The proper way to do this is:

```
import webbrowser as wb
wb.get('chrome %s').open_new_tab('http://www.google.com')
```

To be honest, I'm not really sure that I know the difference between 'chrome' and 'google-chrome', but apparently there is some since they've made the two different type names in the webbrowser documentation.

However, doing this didn't work right off the bat for me. Every time, I would get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\programs\a_temp_testing.py", line 3, in <module>
wb.get('google-chrome')
File "C:\Python34\lib\webbrowser.py", line 51, in get
raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

To solve this, I had to add the folder for chrome.exe to System PATH. My chrome.exe executable file is found at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
```

You should check whether it is here or not for yourself.

To add this to your Environment Variables System PATH, right click on your Windows icon and go to System. System Control Panel applet (Start - Settings - Control Panel - System). Change advanced settings, or the advanced tab, and select the button there called Environment Varaibles.

Once you click on Environment Variables here, another window will pop up. Scroll through the items, select PATH, and click edit.

Once you're in here, click New to add the folder path to your chrome.exe file. Like I said above, mine was found at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
```

Click save and exit out of there. Then make sure you reboot your computer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I suppose the difference between "chrome" and "google-chrome" is due the OS support. In Linux the Chrome package is called "google-chrome" and it is also the way to call it from terminal.

Answer (score 9):

Actually it depends on what kind of uses. If you want to use it in a test-framework I highly recommend [selenium-python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). It is a great tool for testing automation related to web-browsers.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Answer (score 8):

I think it should be

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://gatedin.com')
```

**NOTE: make sure that you give http or https**

if you give "*www.*" instead of "*http:*" instead of opening a broser the interprete displays boolean OutPut **TRUE**.
here you are importing **webbrowser** library

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem.When I define firefox path my problem had been solved.

```
import webbrowser
urL='https://www.python.org'
mozilla_path="C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
webbrowser.register('firefox', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(mozilla_path))
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab(urL)
```

Answer (score 3):

Its a 2 liner! :D
You are a great programmer so never give up!

```
#Use web-browser.

import webbrowser as w
w.open("https://google.com") 

#remember to include https://

#If you want to make a page open if you click a button do this :

from tkinter import *
#^ Imports tk
import webbrowser as w
#^ Imports wb

x = Tk()
#Makes main window

def clicked() :
   w.open("https://google.com")
#Defined the click function. (We'll use this later.)

link = Button(x, text="Click Me!", command=clicked)
link.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
#Our button

x.mainloop()
#Tkinter mainloop
```

Comment: How is the core part of this different from other answers?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply simply achieve it with any python module that gives you an interaction with command line(`cmd`) like `subprocess`, `os`, etc.
but here I came up with examples on only two modules.

Here is syntax (command) `cmd /c start browser_name "URL"`

### Example

```
import os
# or open with iexplore
os.system('cmd /c start iexplore "http://your_url"')

# or open with chrome
os.system('cmd /c start chrome "http://your_url"')
```

```
__import__('subprocess').getoutput('cmd /c start iexplore "http://your_url"')
```

You can also run the command in the cmd it will work to or use other module call
[`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) which mainly used for writing command line utilities.

### here is how

```
import click

click.launch('http://your_url')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a specific browser (e.g. Chrome and Chromium) with command line options like full screen or kiosk mode and also want to be able to kill it later on, then this might work for you:

```
from threading import Timer
from time import sleep

import subprocess
import platform

# Hint 1: to enable F11 use --start-fullscreen instead of --kiosk, otherwise Alt+F4 to close the browser   
# Hint 2: fullscreen will only work if chrome is not already running

platform_browser = {
'Windows': r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk http://stackoverflow.com',
'Linux' : ['/usr/bin/chromium-browser', '--kiosk', 'http://stackoverflow.com']
}

browser = None
def open_browser():
    global browser

    platform_name = platform.system()

    if platform_name in  platform_browser:        
        browser = subprocess.Popen(platform_browser[platform_name])
    else:
        print(":-(")

Timer(1, open_browser).start() # delayed start, give e.g. your own web server time to launch

sleep(20) # start e.g. your python web server here instead

browser.kill()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open any website first you need to import a module called "webbrowser". Then just use webbrowser.open() to open a website.
e.g.

```
 import webbrowser

 webbrowser.open('https://yashprogrammer.wordpress.com/', new= 2)
```