# Iterate through a text file and open the URL on everyline

Tags: python

I'm looking to see if its somehow to possible to open a file containing multiple URLs and open them all in a browser. The text file contains 200+ lines and each line is a unique URL.

Comment: Of course it's possible.

Comment: We might need to know what operating system and browser you are wanting to use. Some operating systems might be able to launch a URL directly with a default browser. On others, you may need to figure out where the web browser lives and want command line arguments are required to have it launch and navigate to the given URL. Also, are you wanting them to open in tabs vs windows?

Comment: They how would you do this in Python?

Comment: @user181895 have you considered learning to write Python code and then doing so?

Comment: Also, you have several problems here: [1] opening a file, [2] iterating over the lines in a file, and [3] opening a string URL in a browser. Try searching for ways to solve each one.... then put them together.

Comment: @JeffBridgman: OS is Windows / Preferable browser is Chrome. I will do so. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31715119/945456

Comment: Have you considered using PowerShell? `gc .\urls.txt |% { start chrome "$_" }`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: I had not considered using powershell and that command did exactly what I was as looking to accomplish. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `webbrowser` module.

```
import webbrowser
with open("filename","r") as f:
    for url in f:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

This will open the `url`s in new tab one by one.

You can learn in detail about `webbrowser` module from [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html)

Comment: The above worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the lines and using webbrowser do something like this

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://example.com')
```