# Do anyone know how to use python webbrowser.open under window

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, html

I had try with python with webbrowser.open, but it only work on IE. How to let it open chrome or firefox. I don't want it to open on IE, i wants to be open on Chrome or Firefox. Due to i try many method, but none of them works.

```
import time
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('www.google.com')
```

Comment: Look at this [How can I open a website in my web browser using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715119/how-can-i-open-a-website-in-my-web-browser-using-python/53963977#53963977)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need specify your `webbrowser's name`, detal see [webbrowser.get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get)

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('www.google.com')
a = webbrowser.get('firefox')
a.open('www.google.com') # True
```

***UPDATE***
If you have `chrome` or `firefox` installed in your computer, do as following:

```
chrome_path =r'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' # change to your chrome.exe path  
# webbrowser is just call subprocess.Popen, so make sure this work in your cmd firstly
# C:\Users\Administrator>C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe www.google.com

# there two way solve your problem
# you have change \ to / in windows
# this seems a bug in browser = shlex.split(browser) in windows
# ['C:UsersAdministratorAppDataLocalGoogleChromeApplicationchrome.exe', '%s']
a = webbrowser.get(r'C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s')
a.open('www.google.com')  #True
# or by register 
webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(r'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'))
a = webbrowser.get('chrome')
a.open('www.google.com')  #True
```

else you can try [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium), it provide much more functions and only need [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

Comment: i try with it \, and it will pop up:                                                             
>>> a = webbrowser.get('firefox')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\webbrowser.py", line 51, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
>>>