# Redirecting to a website in Python

Tags: python, redirect, admin, panel

I'm at Day 1 on Python and I've just made this Admin Login Page script.
I would love if it redirects you to a website when you insert the correct username and password.
I've already searched on stackoverflow for this but I can't get something "easy".
Any suggestions?

```
print ("Pannello di Log-In in caricamento")
import time
time.sleep (2)
username=raw_input ("USERNAME: ")
if username=="admin":
    time.sleep (1)
    print (" ")
else:
    time.sleep (1)
    print (" ")
password=raw_input ("PASSWORD: ")
if password=="psw":
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("LOGGING-IN")
else:
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("LOGGING-IN")
```

Comment: Which website? is it your own site? are you building a website using Python?

Comment: If this is day 1, just carry on with little scripts doing `print`, `if` and `raw_input`. Don't worry about redirecting and websites. You're not there yet.

Comment: I think this was a very good and clear question for someone that has written python for 1 day, I don't think it deserves downvotes.

Comment: I think "redirect" confuses people because they think you're writing a web application, but your code just looks like vanilla python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open a website in my web browser using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715119/how-can-i-open-a-website-in-my-web-browser-using-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To open a web page from python:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://example.com')  # Go to example.com
```