# OSError: No such file or directory with python webbrowser

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

If I run the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import webbrowser

handle = webbrowser.get()
handle.open('https://www.google.com')
```

I have the following error

```
# p-vim try.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 5, in <module>
  handle.open('https://wwww.google.com',new=2)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/webbrowser.py", line 275, in open
  success = self._invoke(args, True, autoraise)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/webbrowser.py", line 238, in _invoke
  stderr=inout, preexec_fn=setsid)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is the origin of the error?

Comment: maybe you should use 3 `w` instead of 4 ? :D

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715119/how-can-i-open-a-website-in-my-web-browser-using-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: `# xdg-open google.com` leads to `xdg-open: file 'google.com' does not exist`